# Persistent filter datasource query on rendering

Tags: filter, sitecore, rendering, datasource, sitecore8

Is it possible to add a persistent filter when selecting the associated content on a rendering, when you choose a datasource query?
[image: Click to see image: Select Associated Content]

Like you can do with a Persistent bucket filter for the search:
[image: Click to see image: Search]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the document [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/create_a_default_and_a_persistent_search_query) https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/create_a_default_and_a_persistent_search_query

To be honest, I never get it working even for a single field. Someone from sitecore need to explain it more details, so try and try more. :)

Sanjay